# Animating through listbox items in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, animation, listbox

I have a ListBox bound to a collection of custom objects.  I have an ItemTemplate set up for displaying those items.  Each item takes up a large rectangular area, so what I want to do is actually only display one item at a time.  After ten seconds, I want to animate (maybe slide in/out or fade in/out) to the next item so that only that one is displayed and so on.

I can't get to grips with how to achieve this, can anyone help please?

Maybe a listbox isn't even the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not dead set on using a listbox, you can get this effect using a TransitioningContentContol instead. [How-to Video here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-toolkit-animatedtransition-control/) (the control is in system.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit). It is now part of the released toolkit (the video is old).

Part of the demo shows how to emulate exactly the behaviour you are after. You can add a slider to the side if you still want it to look a bit like a listbox (and change the selection in response to the slider value changes).

Comment: Thanks.  The TransitioningContentControl works perfectly!
I extended it so that I could add an ItemsSource property.  My new control automatically cycles through the items in ItemsSource on a time.